# Python take the string of anything, ignoring all escape characters

Tags: python, string, string-literals

I am trying to make a function that takes typically copy-pasted text that very often includes `\n` characters. An example of such is as follows:

```
func('''This
is

some
text
that I entered''')
```

The problem with this function is the text can sometimes be rather large, so taking it line by line to avoid `'`, `"` or `'''` isn't plausible. A piece of text that can cause issues is as follows:

```
func('''This
is'''

some"
text'
that I entered''')
```

I wanted to know if there is any way I can take the text as seen in the second example and use it as a string regardless of what it is comprised of.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to extract full strings, minus the newline characters? The output would be `This is some text that I entered`?

Comment: No, I'm looking to extract the full strings and the new line characters, so the output would be `This\nis'''\n\nsome"\ntext'\nthat I entered`

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're trying to do here.  Can you provide an example of how this string causes a problem?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you won't be able to paste the text directly into your file. However, you could paste it into a text file.

Use regex to find triple quotes `'''` and other invalid characters.

Example python:

```
def read_paste(file):
    import re

    with open(file,'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    for i,line in enumerate(data):
        data[i] = re.sub('("|\')',r'\\\1',line)

    output = str()
    for line in data:
        output += line

    return output
```

Comment: If what you say is true then this question simply doesn't have an answer. While this is a valid way of saving the example strings I gave into a string object, it wont work for inside the file, so I can't mark this as answered